# Paging in SQL with no break on primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to Stackoverflow. Please forgive me if I have made some mistake.

I have following data in SQL.

```
Row No.  Customer No.  Customer Name
------------------------------------------------------------
1        1234          ABCD
2        1234          ABCD
3        1234          ABCD
4        6789          WXYZ
5        6789          WXYZ
6        3456          OPQR
7        4567          JKLM
```

I need to page the above data with following constraint

- Page size : 4 records
- If customer no. is splitting between two pages then new customer no. should go on the next page.

output desired:

Paging with 4 records each page

1st Page

```
Row No.  Customer No.  Customer Name
------------------------------------------------------------
1        1234          ABCD
2        1234          ABCD
3        1234          ABCD
```

2nd Page

```
Row No.  Customer No.  Customer Name
------------------------------------------------------------
4        6789          WXYZ
5        6789          WXYZ
6        3456          OPQR
7        4567          JKLM
```

Please help.

Comment: This sort of processing usually occurs in the presentation layer and not in the db layer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response @GiorgosBetsos. I am integrating two systems and the receiver  system requires data in above format. The sender system is SQL.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: I am using MSSQL

Comment: What is the purpose of `RowNo` column? Does it have to bi ordered by it or you want order by Customer? What happens if customer 1234 shows up again in row 8?

Comment: Also what happens if you have more rows for customer then the page size?

Answer (score 0):

You can read page size +1 records using any limiting, then if the last record and the record before the last has the same Customer Name just filter out the customer using HAVING.

Could be tricky and depends on DB you use and could be easily done on presentation layer

Comment: This is very tricky...The above data was dummy ....I have almost 50-60 fields in each record...so HAVING clause will create problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @PageNumber INT = 1,  @PageSize   INT = 4
;with cte1(RowNo,CustomerNo,CustomerName)
AS
(
Select 1,1234,'ABCD' union all
Select 2,1234,'ABCD' union all
Select 3,1234,'ABCD' union all
Select 4,6789,'WXYZ' union all
Select 5,6789,'WXYZ' union all
Select 6,3456,'OPQR' union all
Select 7,4567,'JKLM' 
)
select * from cte1 order by RowNo
 OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNumber - 1) ROWS
      FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done and not to complicated using recursive CTE.

For sample data, I have used query from other answer

```
WITH cte1(RowNo,CustomerNo,CustomerName)
AS
(
    SELECT 1,1234,'ABCD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,1234,'ABCD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,1234,'ABCD' UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,6789,'WXYZ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,6789,'WXYZ' UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,3456,'OPQR' UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,4567,'JKLM' 
)
SELECT * INTO #table FROM cte1
```

I'l add one more row with reapaing user to split this to 3rd page

```
INSERT #table (RowNo, CustomerNo, CustomerName) VALUES (8,3456,'OPQR')
```

And here is the solution. I've put some comments to explain parts

```
WITH CTE_Source AS 
(
    --I use this to add RN column simply beacuse I can't trust that rowNo column will have no gaps
    SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNo) RN 
    FROM #table t
)
, CTE_R AS 
(
    --First part is select of first row
    SELECT s.RowNo
         , s.CustomerNo
         , s.CustomerName
         , s.RN
         , 1 AS Grp --this is a current group of rows
         , 1 AS Cnt --counter of how many rows group have
    FROM CTE_Source s WHERE RN = 1
    UNION ALL
    --subsequent select is for next row
    SELECT 
         s.RowNo
         , s.CustomerNo
         , s.CustomerName
         , s.RN 
         -- increase group when different customer 
         , CASE WHEN s.CustomerNo = r.CustomerNo THEN r.Grp ELSE r.Grp+Cnt END
         -- increase counter when same customer
         , CASE WHEN s.CustomerNo = r.CustomerNo THEN r.Cnt + 1 ELSE 1 END
    FROM CTE_R r
    INNER JOIN CTE_Source s ON s.RN = r.Rn + 1

)
, CTE_Paging AS 
(
    SELECT *
    , CEILING((r.Grp + r.Cnt) / 4.) AS Page -- replace 4 with your page size
    FROM CTE_R r
)
SELECT * FROM CTE_Paging --Just add WHERE Page = if you want specific page
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0) -- for unlimited recursion if you have more than 100 rows
```

Comment: Thanks @NenadZivkovic....It is working for the given dummy records....Will test it for my actual records and let you know the result. :)